# Which sub-topics of math are more "categorical"?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

Sorry that this is kind of a vague question.

I really like when category theory shows up in various areas of math, and I know that some areas utilize category theory more than others. However, even in the areas that utilize a lot of category theory, there are often a lot of sub-topics that don't utilize any category theory (at least, it doesn't seem obvious to me). For example, in group theory, one can think of the first isomorphism theorem through the lens of category theory, but it's not obvious to me how one might think about, e.g., the Sylow theorems in a categorical way.

To refine my question a bit more, I'm looking for things which aren't all that obscure; things which most 1st or 2nd year grad students would probably know something about, but maybe haven't been introduced to those topics through the lens of category theory.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean 1st or 2nd year **undergrad** students?

Comment: A lot of algebraic geometry and topology are categorical in nature

Comment: @KennyLau No. Why? For many institutions, 1st or 2nd year undergrads are (maybe) just barely learning what a group is, so they wouldn't have a very robust catalogue of areas where category theory would show up.

Comment: Adding to Don Thousand's comment: A (nice) topological space is the same thing as an $(\infty,0)$-category.

Comment: The premise seems off. Categorical areas are generally treated categorically. That's why category theory exists.

Comment: Maybe constructing $\text{Ext}^i(-,-)$ and $\text{Tor}_i(-,-)$ through model categories would be interesting to you? @Bears